# Setting properties on parent prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I've been experimenting with prototypal inheritance, as in the following snippet.

```
function extend(c, p) {
    function f() { this.constructor = c; }
    f.prototype = p.prototype;
    c.prototype = new f();
}

function Parent() {}
function Child() {}

extend(Child, Parent);

var p = new Parent();
var c = new Child();

// Child.prototype.say = function () { alert("child"); };
Parent.prototype.say = function () { alert("parent"); };

p.say();
c.say();
```

When running this script, two alerts displaying `parent` will show up.

If I uncomment the commented line, however, the first alert displays `parent`, while the second displays `child`.
At a first glance, it was quite unexpected. It would seem that `Parent.say` would *override* `Child.say`, since it is set later on.

From my understanding, since `Child.prototype` is an instance of an object, an instance of `f`, all properties set on this prototype are set directly on that particular instance of `f`.

When calling `c.say`, the following happens:

1. If `say` was set directly on `c`, call it. It is never set directly on the instance, so, skip to 2.
2. Look for `say` in `Children.prototype`, the instance of `f`. Again, look for a property set directly on the instance of `f`. If the line is **uncommented**, `say` is found here, and the search stops.
3. Look for `say` in `f.prototype`, which is `Parent.prototype`. This is where `say` is found, when the line remains **commented**.

**Q:** Did I understand correctly how JavaScript looks for the property? If this is the case, that would explain why the child property isn't *overridden* by the parent property, when the line is uncommented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Did I understand correctly how JavaScript looks for the property?

Essentially, yes. But it's important to note that the underlying prototype of an object is set by the `new` operation to point to the object referenced by the constructor function's `prototype` property, at which point if you pointed the constructor's `prototype` property at a completely different object, it wouldn't have any effect on *existing* children. The children refer to the object, not the property.

So in general, property lookup works like this:

- Does the property exist on the object itself? If so, use its value.
- No, does the property exist on the object's underlying prototype? If so, use its value.
- Does it exist on its *prototype's* prototype? If so, use the value.
- And so on until we find the property, or run out of prototypes.

Let's throw some ASCII-Art at what you're building there, just for fun:

```
+-----------+
| Parent    |<---------------------------+
+-----------+                            |
| prototype |---------->+-------------+  |
+-----------+      +--->|  (object)   |  |
                   | +->+-------------+  |
                   | |  | constructor |--+       +------------------+
                   | |  | say         |--------->|    (function)    |
                   | |  +-------------+          +------------------+
                   | |                           | alert("parent"); |
                   | |                           +------------------+
                   | |
                   | +--------------------------------------------------+
                   |                                                    |
                   +-----------------------+                            |
+-----------+                              |                            |
| Child     |<---------------------------+ |                            |
+-----------+           +-------------+  | |                            |
| prototype |------+--->|  (object)   |  | |                            |
+-----------+      |    +-------------+  | |                            |
                   |    | constructor |--+ |                            |
                   |    | __proto__   |----+     +------------------+   |
                   |    | say         |--------->|    (function)    |   |
                   |    +-------------+          +------------------+   |
                   |                             | alert("child");  |   |
+-----------+      |                             +------------------+   |
|     c     |      |                                                    |
+-----------+      |                                                    |
| __proto__ |------+                                                    |
+-----------+                                                           |
                                                                        |
+-----------+                                                           |
|     p     |                                                           |
+-----------+                                                           |
| __proto__ |-----------------------------------------------------------+
+-----------+
```

...where `__proto__` is the hidden property that represents the object's link to its prototype. (Some engines actually expose this, and there's a proposal to add that to the standard.)

As you can see, `Child.prototype` and the `c` instance's `__proto__` both point to the same object (and similarly for `Parent.prototype` and `p`'s `__proto__`).

The reason I make the distinction in my first paragraph above is this:

```
function Foo() {
}
Foo.prototype.a = 1;
var f1 = new Foo();
Foo.prototype = {b: 2}; // Putting an entirely new object on `prototype`, not just modifying it
var f2 = new Foo();
console.log(f1.a); // "1"
console.log(f1.b); // "undefined"
console.log(f2.a); // "undefined"
console.log(f2.b); // "2"
```

`f1` and `f2` end up having completely different prototypes, and by the end of the above, `f1`'s `__proto__` no longer refers to the same object `Foo.prototype` refers to.

For this reason, except in very specific situations (like your `extend` function), I strongly recommend **not** assigning new objects to the `prototype` property of a constructor function, because it can get really confusing. :-) Your `extend` function is, again, an exception.

Comment: Makes sense. The reason why the existing instances are affected is that both the instances' prototype and the constructor's prototype still remain the same object.

Comment: @afsantos: Right, they're both pointing to the same object, so adding properties to that object shows up through both references.

Comment: Superb answer! Bonus points for the ASCII art, there should be a tool to illustrate these things automatically.